# Radio button tracking by ID with multiple option but only one select at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function() {

 return $('input[type=radio][name=sponsor_type_0_amount]:checked').attr('value');
 
  }
```

```html
<div id="fadder-amount-type-0" class="form-section-sub sponsor-type-selector-item-sub " title="">
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_230" title="amount_230" value="230" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked"></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_230" class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked">230 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_250" title="amount_250" value="250" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio "></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_250" class="ui-radio ">250 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_300" title="amount_300" value="300" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio "></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_300" class="ui-radio ">300 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="other-amount text-inline" title="">
    <label for="fadder-sponsor_type_0_amount_other">Annat belopp
      <input maxlength="4" size="4" name="sponsor_type_0_amount_other" type="number" id="fadder-sponsor_type_0_amount_other" value="" onkeydown="limitTextArea(this, 10);" onkeyup="limitTextArea(this, 10);">(minst 230 kr/mån)</label>
  </div>
  <p style="margin:5px -20px;">Vill du ge bort ett fadderskap eller bli fadder till mer än ett barn? Kontakta oss på 040 - 12 18 85 eller <a href="mailto:info@barnfonden.se">info@barnfonden.se</a> så hjälper vi dig gärna.</p>
</div>
```

Sending Correct value like 250, try get label text

```
    <label for="fadder-amount_300" class="ui-radio ">300 kr/mån</label>
```

on select should be capture  - 300 kr/mån

Comment: Which button click? What is the problem? Your code seems fine, although could be simplified by using `map()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I want get radio button text  - http://screencast.com/t/snolgLzw8ett

Comment: In which case the array is redundant as you can only select a single option from a radio group. I added an answer for you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes want track select a single option and not group

Answer (score 0):

To select the text of the `label` related to the `input`, attach a `change` event handler to it and traverse the DOM, like this:

```js
$('div#fadder-amount-type-0 input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var labelText = $(this).nextAll('label').text();
  console.log(labelText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fadder-amount-type-0" class="form-section-sub sponsor-type-selector-item-sub " title="">
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_230" title="amount_230" value="230" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked"></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_230" class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked">230 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_250" title="amount_250" value="250" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio "></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_250" class="ui-radio ">250 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="sponsor_type_0_amount" id="fadder-amount_300" title="amount_300" value="300" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio "></span>
    <label for="fadder-amount_300" class="ui-radio ">300 kr/mån</label>
  </div>
  <div class="other-amount text-inline" title="">
    <label for="fadder-sponsor_type_0_amount_other">Annat belopp
      <input maxlength="4" size="4" name="sponsor_type_0_amount_other" type="number" id="fadder-sponsor_type_0_amount_other" value="" onkeydown="limitTextArea(this, 10);" onkeyup="limitTextArea(this, 10);">(minst 230 kr/mån)</label>
  </div>
  <p style="margin:5px -20px;">Vill du ge bort ett fadderskap eller bli fadder till mer än ett barn? Kontakta oss på 040 - 12 18 85 eller <a href="mailto:info@barnfonden.se">info@barnfonden.se</a> så hjälper vi dig gärna.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio text is not capturing when I am selecting selecting Radio button

Comment: You're right - my mistake. I missed the `span` between the `input` and `label`. You need `nextAll()`, not `next()`

Comment: individually  want when click on radio button  - http://screencast.com/t/unKDZwFuQoVb

Comment: Just check with console, is not working - http://screencast.com/t/D08To8Zks

Comment: That's not how you test it. The console is logging all the radio elements selected from the jQuery object - which is why you see them all. As you can see from the snippet above this works fine. If you still have issue I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: Still is not figure out, How to get label text when some body select radio button

Comment: I don't understand where you issue is - does the code above in the snippet do what you require? If so, the issue must lie in your version of it

Comment: finally start send correct value if you help modified get label text - function() {

 return $('input[type=radio][name=sponsor_type_0_amount]:checked').attr('value');
 
  }